# What About The Converse of Lagrange's Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given a positive integer $n$, a group $G$ of order $n$, and a divisor $d$ of $n$, in what cases can we be assured of the existence of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ of order $d$?

What's the situation in the case of the symmetric group on $m$ letters or for the alternating group?

What's the most general statement in each case?

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114378/when-does-every-group-with-order-divisible-by-n-have-a-subgroup-of-order-n). In terms of $d$, we cannot do any better than Sylow's theorem. If $d$ is not a power of a prime, then there exists a group of order divisible by $d$ but with no subgroup of order $d$. In terms of $G$, the groups that satisfy the converse of Lagrange's theorem are called CLT groups. You can show that supersolvable groups are CLT and that CLT groups are solvable.

Answer (score 5):

See these two links to have additional information:

[The inverse of Lagrange's Theorem is true for finite supersolvable group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/267557/8581)

and

[A kind of converse of Lagrange's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41731/8581). In the second one, there is a great classification for the problem done by missed @Arturo Magidin.

Comment: Helpful links! +1

Answer (score 4):

Sylow's theorems deal with the case when $d$ is a prime power. One can show that if $d$ is *not* a prime power, then there's a multiple $n$ of $d$ and a group $G$ of order $n$ with no subgroups of order $d$.

Here's a reference (please let me know if it is not accessible): [Donald McCarthy,
Sylow's theorem is a sharp partial converse to Lagrange's theorem. 
Math. Z. 113 (1970) 383-384.](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/552/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01110508.pdf?auth66=1360757696_9be0a54b67e7088fc898c861468d7eca&ext=.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Two general theorem are:

Cauchy's Theorem: If $G$ is a finite group and $p$ is a prime number dividing $|G|$ then $G$ has an element of order $p$ (and thus a subgroup of order $p$).

Every $p$ group $G$ has a subgroup of any order dividing $|G|$.