# Is G a CLT group if its order is product of distinct prime?

Tags: finite-groups

Let G be group whose order is square-free. Is G always CLT group?

Trying to apply Hall's theorem but not conclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every finite group of square-free order is supersolvable, and hence a CLT-group. For proofs and references see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300113/what-about-the-converse-of-lagranges-theorem), and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267557/the-inverse-of-lagranges-theorem-is-true-for-finite-supersolvable-group). One should explain that a group is called *$CLT$-group*, or *Lagrangian group*, if for each positive divisor of the group order, there exists at least one subgroup of that order.

Remark: For a longer and more detailed account on CLT-groups here on MSE see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144077/complete-classification-of-the-groups-for-which-converse-of-lagranges-theorem-h).